# PostgreSQL: unable to save special character (regional language) in blob

Tags: database, postgresql, blob, special-characters, bytea

I am using PostgreSQL 9.0 and am trying to store a bytea file which contains certain special characters (regional language characters - UTF8 encoded). But I am not able to store the data as input by the user.

For example :

**what I get in request while debugging**: 
`<sp_first_name_gu name="sp_first_name_gu" value="ઍયેઍ"></sp_first_name_gu><sp_first_name name="sp_first_name" value="aaa"></sp_first_name>`

**This is what is stored in DB**: 
`<sp_first_name_gu name="sp_first_name_gu" value="\340\252\215\340\252\257\340\253\207\340\252\215"></sp_first_name_gu><sp_first_name name="sp_first_name" value="aaa"></sp_first_name>`

Note the difference in value tag. With this issue I am not able to retrieve the proper text input by the user. 
Please suggest what do I need to do?

PS: My DB is UTF8 encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is stored correctly, but is escaped into octal escape sequences upon retrieval.

To fix that - change the settings of the DB driver or chose different different encoding/escaping for bytea.

Or just use proper field types for the XML data - like `varchar` or `XML`.

Answer (score 0):

Your string `\340\252\215\340\252\257\340\253\207\340\252\215` is exactly `ઍયેઍ` in octal encoding, so postgres stores your data correctly. PostgreSQL escapes all non printable characters, for more details see postgresql [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-binary.html), especially section 8.4.2